# FirebaseDatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How should I read this data from firebase? 
Because this is a serious issue, Let me explain the issue briefly. 
So, like in the below json image I have a single data **max_slide** which I need to retrieve but I can't because of the below **Exception**.

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap

And this exception is showing because there is no list in the JSON for now. But when I add some data there to make a list is in JSON. There was no such exception. 
[image: Firebase JSON Format]

**Exceptions Occur Only When A Single Data exist!**

Below code, I'm using to retrieve data. Where is the fault?

```
        lessonProgressList = new ArrayList<>();
        mDatabaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("/lesson");
        mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

                    for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DataSnapshot Loop");
                        Lesson lesson = ds.getValue(Lesson.class);     // THIS LINE THROWING THE EXCEPTION
                        lessonProgressList.add(lesson);
                    }

                    listener.updateLessonsProgress(lessonProgressList);
                    Log.d(TAG, "DataSnapshot Success");

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed!");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });
```

Lesson.java  class

```
public class Lesson implements Serializable{

    private List<Topic> topic;

    public Lesson() {
    }

    public Lesson(List<Topic> topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public List<Topic> getTopic() {
        return topic;
    }
}
```

Topic.java

```
public class Topic implements Serializable {
    private int max_slide;

    public Topic(int max_slide) { this.max_slide = max_slide; }

    public Topic() { }

    public int getMax_slide() {
        return max_slide;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `Lesson` class look like?

Comment: Please help I've added the Lesson.java class.

Comment: Hmm... I don't immediately see the problem. Hopefully somebody else spots it.

Comment: Thanks #Frank van. I fixed that issue by inserting some initial value in the Firebase DB. So that whenever I retrieve value it receives because now it has a list but with some initial values. I would like to show you some details. Please check that out after my edit.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Here in this example, I'm using interface because I've separated all the database related methods in a Java class.

```
lessonProgressList = new ArrayList<>();
        mDatabaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("classroom/users/SubhojitHalderUid/lessons_progress/lesson");
        mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

                    for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DataSnapshot Loop");
                        Log.d(TAG, "DataSnapshot Loop" );
                        Lesson lesson = ds.getValue(Lesson.class);
                        lessonProgressList.add(lesson);
                    }

                    listener.updateLessonsProgress(lessonProgressList);
                    Log.d(TAG, "DataSnapshot Lessons Progress Success");

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DataSnapshot Failed!");
                    //setup lesson progress ..          //  STEP 1
                    listener.setupLessonsProgress();    //  INVOKING AN INTERFACE METHODE TO WRITE SOME INISTIAL VALUE IN THE DB
                                                        //  IF dataSnapshot.exists() == false

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());

            }
        });
```

Defined interface method in a Activity class

```
@Override
    public void setupLessonsProgress() {
        Log.d(TAG, "mLessonsList: " + mLessonsList.size());

        for (int x = 0; x < mLessonsList.size(); x++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "lessons " + x);
            for (int c = 0; c < mLessonsList.get(x).getTopics().size(); c++) {
                Log.d(TAG, "topic " + c);
                String writeTo = "lesson/"        // CONSTRUCTED DATABASE REF. PATH
                        + x
                        + "/topic/"
                        + c
                        +"/max_slide";
                database.writeData(writeTo, 0);  // PASSING REFERENCE PATH AND VALUE ZERO  
            }                                    // AS MY REQUIRED INITIAL VALUE
        }

        database.readLessonsProgress("");  // THEN RETRIEVE DATA FROM THE DATABASE
    }
```

Here is the simple method to write

```
public void writeData(String path, int data) {
        Log.d(TAG, "path: " + path + "   data: " + data);
        mDatabaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(path);
        mDatabaseReference.setValue(data);
    }
```

After writing, see the below JSON image, that's what I need. And the cool thing is that the above interface method only called once if there is no such dataSnapshot exists.

[image]